# (German) Do the words "schwitzen" and "wichsen" rhyme?

Tags: pronunciation

I have been in heated debate with a friend of mine who argues vehemently that these words, which I think do rhyme according to the common definitions, do not rhyme.
Do they? Also do "Polster" and "Revolver"?

Comment: Rhymes (and near-rhymes, partial rhymes, eye-rhymes, etc.) are notoriously ill-defined – and it’s not binary rhyme vs non-rhyme but a scale from ‘rhymes perfectly’ to ‘doesn’t rhyme at all’. Entire books have been written trying to arrive at some sort of consensus or definition, usually without much luck. I would say, though, that you’d probably be hard pressed to find native English speakers who would consider _polster_ and _revolver_ an adequate rhyme.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: There are different conventions between languages as well. Since German is so sound rich, the standards for rhymes are correspondingly more lax. Wikipedia gives the example (from Friedrich Schiller's "An die Freude"): *Deine Zauber binden wieder / Alle Menschen werden Brüder* The *ie* and *ü* are different vowel sounds, but Schiller considered them close enough for a rhyme. I'm thinking there's a whole cultural context to consider as well. For example Shakespeare's standards would be different than Bob Dylan's.

Comment: @RDBury Absolutely. Any principle or ‘rule’ regarding rhyme will always be applicable only to a specific language and time – you can’t compare rhyming conventions across languages. The Schiller example is very interesting; I would never have guessed that could ever be considered a rhyme, and I wonder whether Germans nowadays would consider that those two lines rhyme.

Comment: @RDBury.Rhymes between /i/ and /ü/ are commonplace in classical German poetry. In Schiller’s case there is the further consideration that as Schwabe he presumably pronounced both the same..

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Please do not post answers in comments! See: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast That was not an answer; it was an elaboration to a close-flag. The question is not practically answerable as phrased, for the reasons I stated.

Answer (score 3):

"Rhyme" means that the last stressed vowel and everything after it are the same. /itsen/ and /iksen/ do not rhyme, but they are a near rhyme.

Comment: ... are *phonetically* the same.

Comment: @HalvarF. Of course.

Answer (score 3):

They do not rhyme, but there is a rhyming device called "assonance" (in German: "Assonanz" or "Halbreim"). Basically it means that two ending syllables sound similar enough to be accepted by the hearing ear as a rhyme.

For instance Brentanos "Romanzen vom Rosenkranz":

> Schwarze Damen, schwarze Herren
> wandeln durch Bolognas Straßen.
> Werden sie zur Leiche gehen?
> Wen bringt man so spät zu Grabe?

Or Ernst Jandls poem "Ottos Mops":

> ottos mops trotzt
> otto: fort mops fort
> ottos mops hopst fort
> otto: soso

What makes these examples "almost rhyme" is rhythmical similarity along with an identical or almost identical series of vowels:

> Schwarze Damen, schwarze Herren
> [a-e-a-e]-[a-e-e-e-]

Your question is another example of this mechanism, based on the vowel "i" and a similarity of the following consonants when spoken:

> [i]-k-s-en
> [i]-t-s-en

Answer (score 2):

The differences between rhyme and assonance have been explained in the other answers.

Some examples for illustration:

Goethe almost always used rhymes in the strict sense that @fdb explained:

> Hat der alte Hexen**meister**
> sich doch einmal wegbe**geben!**
> Und nun sollen seine **Geister**
> auch nach meinem Willen **leben.**
> Seine Wort und **Werke**
> merkt ich und den **Brauch**,
> und mit Geistes**stärke**
> tu ich Wunder **auch**.

So did Shakespeare (for his pronunciation), at least in his poems:

> When I consider every thing that **grows**
> Holds in perfection but a little **moment**,
> That this huge stage presenteth nought but **shows**
> Whereon the stars in secret influence **comment**; *<= not sure about moment-comment*
> When I perceive that men as plants in**crease**,
> Cheered and checked even by the self-same **sky**,
> Vaunt in their youthful sap, at height de**crease**,
> And wear their brave state out of memo**ry**;  *<= this [used to rhyme with sky](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199668427.001.0001/acref-9780199668427)*
> Then the conceit of this inconstant **stay**
> Sets you most rich in youth before my **sight**,
> Where wasteful Time debateth with de**cay**
> To change your day of youth to sullied **night**,
> And all in war with Time for love of **you**,
> As he takes from you, I engraft you **new**.

"Polster"-"revolver" or "schwitzen"-"wichsen" are clearly not rhymes by this definition.

In contrast, for example hip hop music has a much looser way of rhyming and doing assonances.

German Example (Sido: "Mein Block"):

> Du in deinem Einfamilien**haus** lachst mich **aus**
> Weil du denkst Du hast alles was Du **brauchst**
> Doch im MV scheint mir die Sonne ausm **Arsch**
> In meinem Block weiß es jeder: Wir sind **Stars!**
> Hier kriege ich alles - Ich muss hier nicht mal **weg**
> Hier hab ich Drogen, Freunde und **Sex**
> Die Bullen könn' kommen, doch jeder weiß Bescheid
> Aber keiner hat was ge**seh'n** also könnt ihr wieder **gehn'**
> OK, ich muss ge**steh'n**: Hier ist es dreckig wie ne **Nutte**
> Doch ich weiß; das wird schon wieder mit'n bisschen **Spucke**
> Mein schöner weißer Platten**bau** wird langsam **grau**
> Drauf geschissen! Ich werd auch alt und **grau** im **MV**

So for Sido, "Arsch"-"Stars", "weg"-"Sex" or "Nutte"-"Spucke" are good enough as rhymes.

English example (Eminem: "Cleaning out my closet")

> Now I would never **diss my** own mama just to get recog**nition**
> Take a second to **listen** 'fore you think this record is **dissing**
> But put yourself in my po**sition**; just try to en**vision**
> Wit**nessing** your mama popping pre**scription** pills in the **kitchen**
> **Bitching** that someone's always going through her purse and shit's **missing**
> Going through public **housing systems**, victim of Münch**hausen's Syndrome**
> My whole **life** I was made to be**lieve** I was **sick when I wasn't**
> 'Til **I grew up**, now **I blew up**, it makes you **sick to your stomach**
> **Doesn't it**? **Wasn't it** the reason you made that C**D for me Ma**?
> So you could **try** to justi**fy** the way you **treated me Ma**?

Clearly, depending on what your exposure to rhymes is from, you will have a very different definition.

Comment: Goethe rhymes Nächte and vermöchte (Divan, Saki nameh, towards the end).

Comment: @fdb: Oh come on. Ein Hesse, der nach Sachsen gezogen ist.

Comment: Ach **neige**,
Du Schmerzen**reiche**,
Dein Antlitz gnädig meiner Not! (Goethe's "Faust"). It is only a rhyme in Hessian dialect.